# ECIES 1363a-2004 implementation in openssl

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I'm using openssl library to implement an ETSI standard and, more specifically, to realize communications with a PKI.
To do that I must use the ECIES encryption scheme but it isn't implemented in openssl.

I have found this piece of code [here in the crypto++ google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cryptopp-users/v5r3gofcnoM/ufsbCJxENTAJ):

```
    int curve_id = EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(EC_KEY_get0_group((EC_KEY*)m_pPrivKey));
            EC_KEY* temp_key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(curve_id);
            size_t uPubLen = i2o_ECPublicKey((EC_KEY*)m_pPrivKey, NULL);
            o2i_ECPublicKey(&temp_key, (const byte**)&pCiphertext, uPubLen); // warnign this moves the pCiphertext pointer
            uCiphertextSize -= uPubLen;

            size_t SecLen = (EC_GROUP_get_degree(EC_KEY_get0_group((EC_KEY*)m_pPrivKey)) + 7) / 8;
            byte* pSec = new byte[SecLen];
            int ret = ECDH_compute_key(pSec, SecLen, EC_KEY_get0_public_key(temp_key), (EC_KEY*)m_pPrivKey, NULL);
            ASSERT(ret == SecLen);

            EC_KEY_free(temp_key);

            CHashFunction GenFx(CHashFunction::eSHA1); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

            uPlaintextSize = (uCiphertextSize > GenFx.GetSize()) ? (uCiphertextSize - GenFx.GetSize()) : 0;

            int mac_key_len = 16;

            int GenLen = uPlaintextSize + mac_key_len;

            uint32 counter = 1;
            CBuffer GenHash;
            while(GenHash.GetSize() < GenLen)
            {
                GenFx.Add(pSec, SecLen);
                CBuffer Buff;
                Buff.WriteValue<uint32>(counter++, true);
                GenFx.Add(&Buff);
                GenFx.Finish();
                GenHash.AppendData(GenFx.GetKey(), GenFx.GetSize());
                GenFx.Reset();
            }
            GenHash.SetSize(GenLen); // truncate

            delete pSec;

            byte* key = GenHash.GetBuffer();
            byte* macKey = key + uPlaintextSize;

            unsigned char* result;
            size_t mac_len = uCiphertextSize - uPlaintextSize;
            ASSERT(mac_len == 20);

            byte* mac_result = new byte[mac_len];

            HMAC_CTX ctx;
            HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);

            HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, macKey, mac_key_len, EVP_sha1(), NULL);
            HMAC_Update(&ctx, pCiphertext, uPlaintextSize);
            HMAC_Final(&ctx, mac_result, &mac_len);
            HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

            Ret = memcmp(pCiphertext + uPlaintextSize, mac_result, mac_len) == 0 ? 1 : 0;

            delete mac_result;

            ASSERT(pPlaintext == NULL);
            pPlaintext = new byte[uPlaintextSize];
            for(int i=0; i < uPlaintextSize; i++)
                pPlaintext[i] = pCiphertext[i] ^ key[i];
```

But I am not sure that it works correctly and I don't know how use this piece of code.

Have anyone already implemented this scheme?

Comment: Does 1363a really describe ECIES as a scheme where HMAC is used as a stream cipher? I'd be *very* surprised if it does, and if it doesn't, above code implements some sort of ECIES scheme but not a well defined one. Personally, IES is always *some kind of* DH followed by *some kind of* encryption; you need a specific *form* of ECIES to be sure on how to implement it.

Comment: @Maarten, here are some links which explain those ECIES standard: [Paper_1](http://jkais99.org/journal/v15n3/SHGSCZ_2014_v15n3_1691/4qlo/4qlo.pdf), [Paper_2](http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/32671/1/V2-I2-P7-13.pdf), [Graphical explanaition](https://www.nominet.uk/how-elliptic-curve-cryptography-encryption-works/)